# Using pug mixin arguments inside attributes using string interpolation

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pug

I'm using angular and pug, and have the following template

```
mixin row(label, value)
    tr       
        td 
            strong= label
        td 
            span= "{{" + value + "}}"
```

Which I'm then using like

```
    +row("Dates", "data.dates")
    +row("Venue", "data.venue")
    +row("Meals", "data.meals")
```

Which is working fine, generating the following, which angular then binds to and populates the data as expected:

```
<tr>
    <td>Dates</td>
    <td>{{data.dates}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Venue</td>
    <td>{{data.venue}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Meals</td>
    <td>{{data.meals}}</td>
</tr>
```

But I'd like to be able to use the value parameter within attributes so I can do stuff like

```
mixin row(label, value)
    tr(ng-show="{value} && {value} !== ''"       
        td 
            strong= label
        td 
            span= "{{" + value + "}}"
```

with the intention that this gets compiled to

```
<tr ng-show="data.dates && data.dates !== ''">
    <td>Dates</td>
    <td>{{data.dates}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-show="data.venue && data.venue !== ''">
    <td>Venue</td>
    <td>{{data.venue}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-show="data.meals && data.meals !== ''">
    <td>Meals</td>
    <td>{{data.meals}}</td>
</tr>
```

But I can't get this to work. I've tried a variety of different escaping techniques:

```
   {value}
   {{value}}
   #{value}
   #{{value}}
   ${value}
   ${{value}}
   \#{value}
   \{value}
```

But nothing has worked. Can't find anything at all in the docs either.

I've come up with a few workarounds, passing the attributes in like

```
+row("Dates", "data.dates")(ng-show="data.dates && data.dates !== ''")
```

which in my final code is really messy

```
mixin row(label, value)
        tr(ng-show!=attributes.ngShow)        
            td 
                strong= label
            td 
                span(class="preserve-newlines" ng-bind-html!=attributes.ngbindhtml)= "{{" + value + "}}" 

+row("Dates", "data.dates")
+row("Venue", "data.venue")(ngShow="data.venue && data.venue !== ''")
+row("Meals", "data.meals")(ngShow="data.meals && data.meals !== ''")
+row("Accommodation", "data.accommodation")(ngShow="data.accommodation && data.accommodation !== ''")
+row("Check-in", "data.checkin")(ngShow="data.checkin && data.checkin !== ''")
+row("Donation", "data.donation")(ngShow="data.donation && data.donation !== ''")
+row("Registration", "data.registration")(ngShow="data.registration && data.registration !== ''")
+row("Contact", "data.contact")(ngShow="data.contact && data.contact !== ''")
+row("Telephone", "data.telephone")(ngbindhtml="getTrusted(data.telephone)" ngShow="data.telephone && data.telephone !== ''")
+row("Email", "data.email")(ngbindhtml="getTrusted(data.email)" ngShow="data.email && data.email !== ''")
```

But at this point, its barely a template and I might as well just copy and paste, since I am already writing all the attributes for each row out separately even though they could be vastly simplified if I could just use string interpolation within attributes inside a pug mixin.

So, how do I use string interpolation within attributes inside a pug mixin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked over on pugs [github](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2757#issuecomment-285990989), and with some help from somebody over there managed to figure it out.

Essentially, the attribute strings are evaluated as plain JavaScript expressions, so any form of building a string will work. I went for ES6 style string interpolation as it seemed nicest, resulting in

```
mixin row(label, model, html)
    tr(ng-show=`${model} && ${model} !== ''`)        
        td 
            strong= label
        td
            if html
                span(class="preserve-newlines" ng-bind-html=`getTrusted(${model})`)= "{{" + model + "}}" 
            else
                span(class="preserve-newlines")= "{{" + model + "}}" 

+row("Dates", "data.dates")
+row("Venue", "data.venue")
+row("Meals", "data.meals")
+row("Accommodation", "data.accommodation")
+row("Check-in", "data.checkin")
+row("Donation", "data.donation")
+row("Registration", "data.registration")
+row("Contact", "data.contact")
+row("Telephone", "data.telephone", true)
+row("Email", "data.email", true)
```